# Python Web Scraping - Find only n items

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am running a scraping script made with Beautiful Soup. I scrape results from Google News and i want to get only the first n results added in a variable as tuple.
The tuple is made by news title and news link. In the full script i have a list of keywords like ['crisis','finance'] and so on, you can disregard that part.
That's the code.

```
import bs4,requests
articles_list = []

base_url = 'https://news.google.com/search?q=TEST%20when%3A3d&hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen' 
request = requests.get(base_url) 
webcontent = bs4.BeautifulSoup(request.content,'lxml') 
        
for i in webcontent.findAll('div',{'jslog':'93789'}):  
            for link in i.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("/articles/")},limit=1): 
                if any(keyword in i.select_one('h3').getText() for keyword in keyword_list): 
                    articles_list.append((i.select_one('h3').getText(),"https://news.google.com"+str(link.get('href'))))
```

Written like this is adding as tuple all the news and link that fulfill the if statement, which may result in a long list. I'd like to take only the first n news, let's suppose five, then i would like the script to stop.

I tried:

```
for _

 in range(5):
```

but i don't understand where to add it exactly, because either the code is not running or is appending the same news 5 times.

I also tried :

```
while len(articles_list)<5:
```

but as the statement is part of a for loop and the variable articles_list is global then it stops appending also for the next object of the scraping.

and finally i tried:

```
for tuples in (articles_list[0:5]): #Iterate in the tuple,
        for element in tuples: #Print title, link and a divisor
            print(element)
        print('-'*80)
```

I am ok to do this last one if there are no alternatives, but i'd avoid as the variable articles_list would anyway contain more elements than i need.

Can you please help me understand what i am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a double loop in your code. To exit both of them, you will need to use `break` twice, once for each loop. You can break on the same condition in both loops.

Try this code:

```
import re
import bs4,requests

keyword_list = ['health','Coronavirus','travel']
articles_list = []

base_url = 'https://news.google.com/search?q=TEST%20when%3A3d&hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen' 
request = requests.get(base_url) 
webcontent = bs4.BeautifulSoup(request.content,'lxml') 

maxcnt = 5  # max number of articles
     
for ictr,i in enumerate(webcontent.findAll('div',{'jslog':'93789'})):
   if len(articles_list) == maxcnt: break   # exit outer loop
   for link in i.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("/articles/")},limit=1): 
       if any(keyword in i.select_one('h3').getText() for keyword in keyword_list): 
           articles_list.append((i.select_one('h3').getText(),"https://news.google.com"+str(link.get('href')))) 
           if len(articles_list) == maxcnt: break  # exit inner loop

print(str(len(articles_list)), 'articles')
print('\n'.join(['> '+a[0] for a in articles_list]))  # article titles
```

Output

```
5 articles
> Why Coronavirus Tests Come With Surprise Bills
> It’s Not Easy to Get a Coronavirus Test for a Child
> Britain’s health secretary says the asymptomatic don’t need tests. Critics say that sends a mixed message.
> Coronavirus testing shifts focus from precision to rapidity
> Coronavirus testing at Boston lab suspended after nearly 400 false positives
```

Comment: Thank you! I solved in a quite different way because i wanted to loop the research for other different items and str(articles_list) would make that loop impossible.
So i added a counter:
"counter = 0"
and then two loop breaker:
"if counter ==5:
       break"
on each for loop.

It works! 
I see my problem was having only one breaker and not two.